# Auto-click 'next page' link & push to array in Chrome DevTools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to push href values to an array, then auto-click the 'next page' link, push more values to the same array, click next page, and so on within the Chrome DevTools console.

I have succeeded in grabbing the first page's href values, pushing them to an array, and auto-clicking to page 2.

My issue is that once on page 2 my array becomes 'undefined' and the loop stops.

Here is my current code:

```
var profiles = [];
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.leftAlignedImage > a:first-child');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    profiles.push((anchors[i].getAttribute('href')));
}
document.querySelectorAll('.next_page').item(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript variables do not persist across pages. You will have to use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to preserve values across pages (within same tab).

After you get all the links in your variable `profiles`, you can save them as a string using sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("links", profiles.join(","));
```

When you want to access the links on a different page (in same tab), you can access them by assigning all the values back to the `profiles` variable:

```
var profiles = sessionStorage.getItem("links").split(",");
```

Alternatively, if you wish to store variable values across multiple tabs, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).